# Configure middleware to check the authentication first then authorization second

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, .net-6.0, middleware

- I have a custom Authorization Handler
- The application is setup to use Auth0
- What I want to achieve to configure the middleware in such way it

  - first checks if the user is Authenticated (if not returns a 401)
  - if the user is Authenticated, I want to hit my custom Requirement.

I have tried the followings but no matter, when I called the endpoint method, the custom Authorization handler is hit without checking if the user is Authenticated or not.

1 -

```
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    options.AddPolicy("RequireDummyRole", policyBuilder => 
    {
         policyBuilder
         .Combine(opt.DefaultPolicy)
         .AddRequirements(new RequireDummyRoleRequirement(Roles.DummyRole))
    })
```

2 -

```
    options.AddPolicy("RequireDummyRole", policyBuilder => 
    {
         policyBuilder
         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
         .AddRequirements(new RequireDummyRoleRequirement(Roles.DummyRole))
    })
```

Comment: How is your program.cs. Could you post the code? The order of `app.use` is important.